# Filtering out other users's notes in Searchkick rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm a beginner to Ruby on Rails working on a Notebook app. I'm trying using Searchkick to enable users to quickly search their notes. I currently have 2 users (via devise gem).

I have just set up Searchkick, but when I search for a word that both the users have in their notes, the result shows notes by both users. So, a user can see the other's note in this case as in the image below.
[image: Notebook]

Here is my `notes_controller.rb` code:

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_note, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @notes = Note.where(user_id: current_user).order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def search
        if params[:search].present?
            @notes = Note.search(params[:search])
        else
          @notes = Note.all
        end
    end

  def new
    @note = current_user.notes.build
  end

  def create
    @note = current_user.notes.build(note_params)
    if @note.save
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Note successfully created."
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show

  end

  def edit

  end

  def update
    if @note.update(note_params)
      redirect_to note_path(@note), notice: "Note successfully updated."
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @note.destroy
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Note successfully deleted."
  end

  private
  def note_params
    params.require(:note).permit(:title, :body)
  end

  def find_note
    @note = Note.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

My `routes.rb` code:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :notes do
    collection do
      get :search
    end
  end

  authenticated :user do
    root "notes#index"
  end

  root "welcome#home"
end
```

My `search.html.erb` code, which is the same as `index.html.erb` code:

```
<% @notes.each do |note| %>
  <h2><%= link_to note.title, note_path(note) %></h2>
<% end %>
```

I have a feeling I need to add a conditional statement in the search action in the notes_controller but that is not working.

Can anyone help please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That would be

`@notes = Note.search params[:search], where: { user_id: current_user.id }`